# UIImageView image not showing up in IPhone 5s,6 and 6+

Tags: ios, object, uiimage, iphone-6

i am facing strange issue in one of my old app when running on iPhone 5s,6 and 6plus.i notice when i run the app on iPhone 5 and ipad its working fine,but when i run the same app in iPhone 5s or later devices all my app screens looks white and it did not showing any image in my entire app.All the other things like Label,tableview working fine on these devices.here is some screen shot of my app

[image]
[image]

As my screen shot shows every thing is ok in iPhone 5 simulator but when it comes to iPone 5S or later devices entire screen is white.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Post your code, please.

Comment: there is no code for these image.these are all static images.

Comment: Does this issue raised in device or in Simulator?

Comment: in Simulator.i have only iphone 5 don't have other devices to test.On iphone 5 it is working fine both in simulator as well in device.

Comment: There may be missing resources that are not copied over because Xcode thinks they are in the existing build.

Try these:   
(1) In the simulator, 'reset content & settings...' for EACH device type that is misbehaving;   
(2) In Xcode,  Product->clean; Product->run.

Comment: facing same problem. Any solution. I think this issue is only on 64 bit devices .

Answer (score 2):

Find the answer..

UIImageView alpha is getting zero. 
In my case, I am using category for UIImageView. I commented that and everything working alright now.

```
@implementation UIImageView (ForScrollView)

//- (void) setAlpha:(float)alpha {
//    [super setAlpha:alpha];
//}
```

Comment: Where is that implementation? I have this problem in iPhone 5 simulator. I just dragged an Image View into my storyboard, I didn't write any code?